# How to change xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I search an example of code that can change my xml file thanks to PhP but I don't find on the Internet. I try to change my tag score1 and score2.
This is (example) my xml code :

```
<Coupe>
<Groupe id = "Groupe A">
    <Match id = "1">
        <Jour> 14/06/2018</Jour>
        <Heure> 17:00</Heure>
        <equipe1>A1</equipe1>
        <equipe2>A2</equipe2>
        <score1> </score1>
        <score2> </score2>
    </Match>
    <Match id = "2">
        <Jour> 15/06/2018</Jour>
        <Heure> 14:00</Heure>
        <equipe1>A3</equipe1>
        <equipe2>A4</equipe2>
        <score1> </score1>
        <score2> </score2>
    </Match>
    <Match id = "3">
        <Jour> 19/06/2018</Jour>
        <Heure> 20:00</Heure>
        <equipe1>A1</equipe1>
        <equipe2>A3</equipe2>
        <score1> </score1>
        <score2> </score2>
    </Match>
    <Match id = "4">
        <Jour> 20/06/2018</Jour>
        <Heure> 17:00</Heure>
        <equipe1>A4</equipe1>
        <equipe2>A2</equipe2>
        <score1> </score1>
        <score2> </score2>
    </Match>
    <Match id = "5">
        <Jour> 25/06/2018</Jour>
        <Heure> 16:00</Heure>
        <equipe1>A4</equipe1>
        <equipe2>A1</equipe2>
        <score1> </score1>
        <score2> </score2>
    </Match>
    <Match id = "6">
        <Jour> 25/06/2018</Jour>
        <Heure> 16:00</Heure>
        <equipe1>A2</equipe1>
        <equipe2>A3</equipe2>
        <score1> </score1>
        <score2> </score2>
    </Match>
</Groupe>
```

This is my PhP code :

```
    <?php  
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('labo7.xml');

  $listeEq1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('score1');
   $listeEq2 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('score2');

   for($i=0;$i<48;$i++){
       //$dom->getElementsByTagName('score1')->item($i);  ?????

   }

$dom->save('labo7.xml');
?>
```

Comment: what is the stray `<Coupe>`?? is there more to this xml file?

Comment: i believe `$dom->getElementsByTagName('score1')->item($i)->nodeValue = value` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to change your tags to - whether that is the value of them or the actual tagname itself but if it is merely the value then the following might help.

```
$xml=__DIR__ . '\\labo7.xml';


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $xml );

$sc1=$dom->getElementsByTagName('score1');
$sc2=$dom->getElementsByTagName('score2');


for( $i=0; $i < $sc1->length; $i++ ){/* assign new values - to what nobody knows */
    $sc1->item( $i )->nodeValue='pomegranate_'.$i;
    $sc2->item( $i )->nodeValue='pineapple_'.$i;
}
$dom->save( __DIR__ . '\\labo7.xml' );

echo __DIR__ . '\\labo7.xml saved';
```